# How can i fetch images in grid view from firebase in flutter

Tags: iphone, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have created grid view and i want to fetch multiple images from firebase database which i inserted manually. I tried to with image.network but it couldn't work.I am not sure if i am doing it right.

I have made async method and used var _firestoreinstance =FirebaseFirestore.instance;

```
QuerySnapshot q = await _firestoreinstance.collection('product').get();


setState(() {
  for (int i = 0; i < q.docs.length; i++) {
    _products.add({
      "Name": q.docs[i]['Name'],
      "Description": q.docs[i]['Description'],
      "Price": q.docs[i]['Price'],
      "product-image": q.docs[i]['product-image'],
      
    });
  }
});
return q.docs;
```

}

GridView.builder(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
crossAxisCount: 2),
itemBuilder: (_, index) {
return Card(
elevation: 3,
child: Column(
children: [

```
                        Image.network(_products[index]["product-image"][0]),
                       Text("${_products[index]["Description"]}"),
                       Text("${_products[index]["Price"].toString()}"),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hi i tried to post the code but this site didnt let me

Comment: Try to strip it down a bit. Or write some _Lorem Ipsum_ to hack it.

Comment: @ArpitaChaudhari Is ```['product-image']``` a list? Because you did this ```_products[index]["product-image"][0]```